# Debugging Firefox on Android

Tags: malware, firefox-for-android, debug

I had the following: on Firefox on Android, some links in a facebook post behaved this way: I got a pop-up window that there's no Internet and I should try again, and then the following screen appeared:

[image]

How can I debug such a mishap, i.e. what happens here?

Comment: You can try [Firefox Remote Debugging](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/about_colon_debugging/index.html).

Comment: Or https://github.com/liriliri/eruda